# npm install on mingw

Tags: node.js, windows, mingw, node-gyp

## Introduction

I want to install `aglio` with npm on Windows:

```
npm install -g aglio
```

It fails when `node-gyp rebuild`, complaining MSB3428.

> MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".

The error message instructs me to install Visual Studio.

## Question

Can I install `aglio` (or any other packages involving `node-gyp`) **without installing VisualStudio**?
(My computer has scarce storage.)

Preferably, I want to make use of MinGW.
(Configuring `GYP_GENERATOR` would solve the problem?)